# Error while configuring pytorch-kaldi on Linux Mint 19.1 cinnamon

Tags: linux, pytorch, linux-mint, cinnamon, kaldi

I am trying to configure `Pytorch`-Kaldi on a `Linux Mint cinnamon 19.1`.

I can not solve this error :

```
ZOE ERROR (from hmm-info): error opening HMM file ((null)/HMM/models)
ZOE library version 2013-02-16
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: it is a toolkit ...